# Notebook wants to reboot constantly

Tags: windows-8, windows-update

I'm having some trouble with my Asus S56CA Ultrabook. When I boot it up, in the login screen it has a message in the bottom right corner saying my computer will restart today to finish installing some updates. After being on for just over 15 minutes, it will then automatically do that.

This has been the case for 2 weeks now, and I've restarted it at least 50 times in the meantime, it just won't go away. When I view the update log there are some new updates in there after every reboot, and the number of updates it says it's installing is different on every reboot, so it can't just be one update failing to install over and over again. I've even gone to Windows Update settings, and set it so it only automatically downloads the updates, but doesn't install them until I tell it to, yet it still automatically reboots every 15 minutes.

I've googled for the problem but haven't found anything similar to this problem. Has anyone ever seen something like this? Is there a quick and easy fix for it or should I just wipe it and reinstall Windows?

Comment: You could try a system restore to before the issues started.

Comment: There must be an option for prompting you before installing the updates.

Comment: @emab there is, I've set it from 'Install updates automatically' to 'Download updates automatically but let me choose whether to install them', but it still doesn't prompt me. It just gives me a countdown to when it will automatically restart, and no way to cancel it.

Comment: @yassarikhan786 I'm trying that right now, will post as to whether it helped in a few minutes.

Comment: It should help.

Comment: @yassarikhan786 It did. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the update, and then Windows Update won't offer it to you again unless you choose to restore it.

To hide an update

Open Windows Update in Control Panel by swiping in from the right edge of the screen, tapping Search (or, if you're using a mouse, pointing to the upper-right corner of the screen, moving the mouse pointer down, and then clicking Search), entering Windows Update in the search box, tapping or clicking Settings, and then tapping or clicking Install optional updates.

Do one of the following:

If you have any important updates, click the link that tells you important updates are available.

If you have any optional updates, click the link that tells you optional updates are available.

Select any update that you want to hide, press and hold or right-click it, tap or click Hide update, and then tap or click OK.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, it isn't just one update that's failing to install. From what I understand, doing this would mean the computer won't update anymore at all, which is definitely not what I want. If that's the only other solution I'd prefer just reinstalling the OS.

Comment: in windows 8 you can also try 1)Refresh your PC without affecting your files & 2)To reset your PC